# Oracle SQL - How to get counts based up on dates into multiple columns in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

I have data like this in a Oracle table

```
REGID SESSION_START_DATETIME USAGEID  
    1 7/11/2016                    1  
    1 6/10/2016                    1      
    1 6/09/2016                    1  
    1 5/04/2016                    1  
    1 5/04/2016                    1  
    1 5/04/2016                    1
```

I need the output like

```
REGID 0-30_days_usagecount 31-60_days_usagecount 61-90_days_usagecount  
    1                    1                     2                     3
```

usagecount is basically count(usage_id)... how to write a query for this problem?

Please help

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking or how you arrived at your output.

Comment: 0-30 days from when? From SYSDATE? Also, what do you want to do with the sessions that are more than 90 days old?

Comment: hi mathguy, Yes 0-30 days from Sysdate. I need to disgregard the sessions that are more than 90 days old

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do this using the PIVOT operator.

```
with 
     inputs (REGID, SESSION_START_DATETIME, USAGEID) as (  
       select 1 , to_date('7/11/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all 
       select 1 , to_date('6/10/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all       
       select 1 , to_date('6/09/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all 
       select 1 , to_date('5/04/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all 
       select 1 , to_date('5/04/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual union all 
       select 1 , to_date('5/04/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 1 from dual
     )
select * from (
  select regid, session_start_datetime,
         case when trunc(sysdate) - session_start_datetime between  0 and 30
                   then  '0-30_days_usagecount'
              when trunc(sysdate) - session_start_datetime between 31 and 60
                   then '31-60_days_usagecount'
              when trunc(sysdate) - session_start_datetime between 61 and 90
                   then '61-90_days_usagecount'
              end
         as col
  from inputs
)
pivot (  count(session_start_datetime)
            for col in ( '0-30_days_usagecount', '31-60_days_usagecount',
                        '61-90_days_usagecount'
                       )
      )
;



     REGID '0-30_days_usagecount' '31-60_days_usagecount' '61-90_days_usagecount'
---------- ---------------------- ----------------------- -----------------------
         1                      1                       2                       3

1 row selected.
```

Comment: VOW!! Worked like a charm. Thanks so much Mathguy

Comment: Hi MathGuy, I just have one more question. In the above query where are you doing the group by reg_id. If I need to do group by on multiple columns how to write the above query? Thanks alot for your help in advance.

Comment: Best way to answer: add a row with a different reg_id and run  exactly the same query, see what happens.

Comment: Hi MathGuy - That worked very good with addition of another reg_id. I have a situation for example 4 columns reg_id, session_id, SESSION_START_DATETIME, USAGEID. I need to group by on reg_id and session_id instead of only reg_id. How can I alter the above query?

Comment: Got it MathGuy. I just needed to add Session_id followed by reg_id. It worked :)

Comment: @beckham - Great! If you are done with this question, you may want to mark it as "answered" - so volunteers can concentrate on unanswered questions.

Comment: Hi MathGuy, Sure. Can you please let me know how to mark the question answered?. I tried to find that option but no luck

Comment: Hi Mathguy, I have posted another question and no response from the users. Would you be able to help me on this. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38627219/how-to-delete-the-records-based-upon-prev-and-next-rows-and-assign-the-date-base

Comment: @beckham - I'll take a look at your other question. I saw other forum members complained about what you posted. All the data is there, and the logic and the desired output. (I will ask on that thread if I have questions). What they are not happy about is the input table. Instead of posting it like you did, it is much, much more helpful if you post CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements (which can be generated quite easily in whatever app you use, like Toad or SQL Server). Otherwise we either must write them ourselves, or not test our solutions. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi MathGuy, I am new to this forum and now getting how to post a question. I have just included the Insert statements as well.

Comment: I have posted a new question with SQL inserts. would you be able to help me on this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38885889/how-to-assign-the-counter-based-on-a-condition-in-oracle

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT regid,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN session_start_dt <= (sysdate - 30)
    THEN usage_id
    ELSE 0
  END) T1,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN session_start_dt   > (sysdate - 30)
    AND session_start_date <= (sysdate -60)
    THEN usage_id
    ELSE 0
  END) T2,
  SUM(
  CASE
    WHEN session_start_dt   > (sysdate - 60)
    AND session_start_date <= (sysdate -90)
    THEN usage_id
    ELSE 0
  END) T3
FROM temp
GROUP BY regid;
```

Comment: Hi User2744722 - I need the counts, not the SUM. While I tried to substitute sum with counts I get the same value in all the fields.

Comment: @beckham - two ways to save this solution. Either change to "count" as you did, but then delete the ELSE part of each CASE (so that the ELSE becomes NULL and is not counted), OR change the THEN value from usage_id to 1. Then adding becomes counting, essentially. What user... shows here is how PIVOT used to be done in the past, before Oracle introduced the PIVOT operator.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select (select count(USAGEID) from tablename where DATEDIFF(day, SESSION_START_DATETIME, CURDATE()) < 31 and REGID = A. REGID) AS 0-30_days_usagecount, (select count(USAGEID) from tablename where DATEDIFF(day, SESSION_START_DATETIME, CURDATE()) > 30 and DATEDIFF(day, SESSION_START_DATETIME, CURDATE()) < 61 and REGID = A. REGID) AS 31-60_days_usagecount, (select count(USAGEID) from tablename where DATEDIFF(day, SESSION_START_DATETIME, CURDATE()) > 60 and DATEDIFF(day, SESSION_START_DATETIME, CURDATE()) < 91 and REGID = A. REGID) AS 61-90_days_usagecount from tablename A group by A.REGID
```