# How to assign the counter based on a condition

Tags: sql, oracle

Source Table DDL :-

```
CREATE TABLE temp (
    REG_ID        NUMBER(5) ,
    Pkg_DES       VARCHAR2(15),
    PRD_DESC      VARCHAR2(15)
    EVENT_DATE    DATE,
    event_type_cd VARCHAR2(15)
)
```

I have insert statements too below -

```
insert into temp (REG_ID, Pkg_DES, PRD_DESC, EVENT_DATE, event_type_cd) 
select 1 , 'CC' , 'trail' , to_date('12/12/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'new sub' from dual union all 
select 1 , 'CC' , 'trail' ,to_date('12/13/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'exp' from dual union all       
select 1 , 'CC' , 'PAID' , to_date('12/14/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'upsell' from dual union all 
select 1 , 'CC' , 'PAID' , to_date('12/15/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy'), 'exp' from dual union all 
select 1 , 'CC' , 'PAID' , to_date('12/16/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'renewal' from dual union all 
select 1 , 'CC' , 'PAID' , to_date('12/17/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'renewal' from dual union all
select 1 , 'aa' , 'trail' , to_date('12/12/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'new sub' from dual union all 
select 1 , 'aa' , 'trail' , to_date('12/13/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'exp' from dual union all       
select 1 , 'aa' , 'PAID' , to_date('12/14/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'renewal' from dual union all 
select 1 , 'aa' , 'PAID' , to_date('12/15/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'renewal' from dual union all 
select 1 , 'aa' , 'PAID' , to_date('12/16/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'upsell' from dual union all 
select 1 , 'aa' , 'PAID' , to_date('12/17/2016', 'mm/dd/yyyy') , 'renewal' from dual;
```

I have the requirement like this below

```
REG_ID | Pkg_DES | PRD_DESC | EVENT_DATE | event_type_cd
-------+---------+----------+------------+--------------
    1  |  CC     |  trail   | 12-12-2012 |  new sub
    1  |  CC     |  trail   | 12-13-2012 |  exp
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-14-2012 |  upsell
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-15-2012 |  exp
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-16-2012 |  renewal
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-17-2012 |  renewal
    1  |  aa     |  trail   | 12-12-2012 |  new sub 
    1  |  aa     |  trail   | 12-13-2012 |  exp
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-14-2012 |  renewal
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-15-2012 |  renewal
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-16-2012 |  upsell 
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-17-2012 |  renewal
```

The output I need is like below:

```
REG_ID | Pkg_DES | PRD_DESC | EVENT_DATE | event_type_cd | renewal_cnt | is_ren | is_conv
-------+---------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------   
    1  |  CC     |  trail   | 12-12-2012 |  new sub      |       0     |     0  |   0
    1  |  CC     |  trail   | 12-13-2012 |  exp          |       0     |     0  |   0
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-14-2012 |  upsell       |       0     |     0  |   1
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-15-2012 |  exp          |       0     |     0  |   1
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-16-2012 |  renewal      |       1     |     1  |   0
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-17-2012 |  renewal      |       2     |     1  |   0
    1  |  aa     |  trail   | 12-12-2012 |  new sub      |       0     |     0  |   0 
    1  |  aa     |  trail   | 12-13-2012 |  exp          |       0     |     0  |   0
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-14-2012 |  renewal      |       0     |     0  |   1
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-15-2012 |  renewal      |       1     |     1  |   0
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-16-2012 |  upsell       |       2     |     1  |   0 
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-17-2012 |  renewal      |       3     |     1  |   0
```

- Conversion Logic :- If a PRD_DESC is changed from Trail to Paid for the 1st time, then it is called CONVERSION product
- Renewal Logic :- If a Paid Product is renewed from Paid to Paid, then it is called RENEWAL product
- renewal_cnt should start only at the PAID to PAID product. If the PAID to PAID is having event_type_cd as exp then the counter shouldn't increment. If the trail to paid is having event_type_cd as renewal then also it should be zero only. the event's are ordered by event_date
- is_conv should be set to 1 for the 1st Trail to Paid product.
- is ren should be set to 1 for the paid to paid product.

Does someone have the idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen -  I have tried to use Rank function and derive the Renewal Counter, but it didn't worked. :(

Comment: Try the `LAG` function

Comment: @ Tim Biegeleisen - I have a query that I am using to achieve the above using OUTER apply function. I have been trying to paste it from last 30 mins. Overstackflow is not allowing me to paste it here.

Comment: @cha, Lag function can't work because of the expiration records i will have in the middle.

Comment: To be exact. Can we just ignore "exp" rows while calculating?

Comment: What is the order of your records? It seems to be `pkg_des desc, event_date asc`, but in your sample data `reg_id` is always 1, so it might also play a role. Please explain in which order the records must be traversed to apply the rules, and when a new "section" starts (different `reg_id` maybe?).

Comment: Several problems with the rules: according to rule (1), there should not be a 1 in `is_conv` for the 4th row. According to rule (2), there should be a 1 in `is_ren` for renewals, but you put 1 also when it is not a renewal, but upsell, in the one-but-last row. According to rule (3) events are ordered by `event_date`, but this is not true in your sample data. According to rule (3), *"If the trail to paid is having event_type_cd as renewal then also it should be zero only"*, but it should be zero anyway when it concerns a *trail to paid*, so this extra condition on `event_type_cd` makes no sense

Comment: What are rule 4 and 5 about? They seem repetitions of rule 1 and 2. Please review your question, and fix all these issues. Please also make sure that this is EXACTLY what you want, and that your sample data and result is correct.

Comment: @trincot, looks like You missed rule about "exp" rows:  _If the PAID to PAID is having event_type_cd as exp then the counter shouldn't increment_

Comment: @Razzka, I *missed* that rule, because that part is clear to me. I just raised questions about things that are not or are conflicting with the sample ;-)

Comment: @trincot, the order is based on event_date from each registration_id and pkg_desc.

Comment: @ trincot, Expiration record is just the shadow of its trailing record. We just need to have the same renewal_cnt, is_ren and is_conv of its trailing record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution of @PonderStibbons is fine, but as I had made one myself, not based on recursion, I post it as well. Note that there will be differences for other data sets. Notably, this query assumes that within a given range of same `pkg_des` records, the group of records with `prd_desc` *PAID* are not interrupted by non-*PAID* values. This is not an assumption made in the recursive solution, which could be an important factor to discard my solution:

```
select   reg_id, pkg_des, prd_desc, event_date, event_type_cd,
         case when prd_desc = 'PAID'
              then greatest(0, -1+count(case when event_type_cd <> 'exp' then 1 end) 
                      over (partition by reg_id, pkg_des, prd_desc
                            order by     event_date asc
                            rows between unbounded preceding and 0 preceding)
                   )
              else 0
         end as renewal_cnt,
         case when   lag(prd_desc) over (partition by reg_id, pkg_des
                                         order by     event_date asc) = 'PAID' 
                 and prd_desc = 'PAID'
                 and event_type_cd = 'renewal'
              then 1 
              else 0 
         end is_ren, 
         case when   lag(prd_desc) over (partition by reg_id, pkg_des
                                         order by     event_date asc) = 'trail'
                 and prd_desc = 'PAID'
              then 1
              else 0
         end is_conv
from     temp
order by reg_id asc,
         pkg_des desc,
         event_date asc;
```

Output is the same for the given sample data:

```
REG_ID | Pkg_DES | PRD_DESC | EVENT_DATE | event_type_cd | renewal_cnt | is_ren | is_conv
-------+---------+----------+------------+---------------+-------------+--------+--------   
    1  |  CC     |  trail   | 12-12-2012 |  new sub      |       0     |     0  |   0
    1  |  CC     |  trail   | 12-13-2012 |  exp          |       0     |     0  |   0
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-14-2012 |  upsell       |       0     |     0  |   1
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-15-2012 |  exp          |       0     |     0  |   0*
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-16-2012 |  renewal      |       1     |     1  |   0
    1  |  CC     |  PAID    | 12-17-2012 |  renewal      |       2     |     1  |   0
    1  |  aa     |  trail   | 12-12-2012 |  new sub      |       0     |     0  |   0 
    1  |  aa     |  trail   | 12-13-2012 |  exp          |       0     |     0  |   0
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-14-2012 |  renewal      |       0     |     0  |   1
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-15-2012 |  renewal      |       1     |     1  |   0
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-16-2012 |  upsell       |       2     |     0* |   0 
    1  |  aa     |  PAID    | 12-17-2012 |  renewal      |       3     |     1  |   0
```

I added an asterisk where the output is different from what you listed in your question, but the above is the output when the rules are followed to the letter.

Comment: Hi Trincot, You are genius. The query works very fine. Actually the output you have listed is correct. Query provided by Ponder worked well too, but its slow as I am doing this on 20 mil records.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, recursion often has a performance penalty, but in favour of recursive queries, I should say I find them more readable in terms of *rules*, and thus easier to maintain (in case you need to change something later). Just saying... ;-)

Comment: I am seeing -1 for some of the renewal_cnt. When can we expect that?

Comment: This would happen when the first `PAID` record is an `exp` also. I improved my answer, which now has a `greatest(0, ...)` to avoid the occurrences of such -1 values.

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 11g you could use recursive query like below:

```
with 
  t as (
      select row_number() over (partition by pkg_des order by event_date) rn, 
             reg_id, pkg_des, prd_desc, event_date, event_type_cd 
        from temp),
  th (rn, reg_id, pkg_des, prd_desc, event_date, event_type_cd, ren_cnt, is_ren, is_conv) 
    as (
      select rn, reg_id, pkg_des, prd_desc, event_date, event_type_cd, 0, 0, 0 
        from t where rn = 1
      union all
      select t.rn, t.reg_id, t.pkg_des, t.prd_desc, t.event_date, t.event_type_cd, 
             case when t.prd_desc = 'PAID' and th.prd_desc = 'PAID' 
                   and t.event_type_cd <> 'exp' 
                  then th.ren_cnt + 1 else th.ren_cnt end,
             case when t.prd_desc = 'PAID' and th.prd_desc = 'PAID' 
                   and t.event_type_cd <> 'exp' 
                  then 1 else 0 end,
             case when t.prd_desc = 'PAID' and th.prd_desc = 'trail' then 1 else 0 end
        from t join th on t.pkg_des = th.pkg_des and t.rn = th.rn + 1 )
select pkg_des, prd_desc, event_date, event_type_cd, ren_cnt, is_ren, is_conv 
  from th order by pkg_des desc, rn;
```

Output:

```
PKG_DES         PRD_DESC        EVENT_DATE  EVENT_TYPE_CD    REN_CNT     IS_REN    IS_CONV
--------------- --------------- ----------- ------------- ---------- ---------- ----------
CC              trail           2016-12-12  new sub                0          0          0
CC              trail           2016-12-13  exp                    0          0          0
CC              PAID            2016-12-14  upsell                 0          0          1
CC              PAID            2016-12-15  exp                    0          0          0
CC              PAID            2016-12-16  renewal                1          1          0
CC              PAID            2016-12-17  renewal                2          1          0
aa              trail           2016-12-12  new sub                0          0          0
aa              trail           2016-12-13  exp                    0          0          0
aa              PAID            2016-12-14  renewal                0          0          1
aa              PAID            2016-12-15  renewal                1          1          0
aa              PAID            2016-12-16  upsell                 2          1          0
aa              PAID            2016-12-17  renewal                3          1          0
```

Subquery `T` only numbers rows in proper order. Main subquery `TH` is recursive. There is difference in row 4, in column `is_conv`, but I followed Your rules, so the conditions in `case when` may need little adjustments.

Explanations and examples of recursive CTE: [1](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/recursive-subquery-factoring-11gr2), [2](http://it.toolbox.com/blogs/data-ruminations/recursive-cte-vs-connect-by-45422).