# Oracle - Assigning the correct Date from a Set

Tags: sql, oracle, function

I have a table A like below

```
REGID  | PKG_DESC  | EVENT_DATE   | IS_CON  | IS_REN
-----------------------------------------------------
1234   | cc        | 27-MAR-14     |  0      |  0
1234   | cc        | 27-JUN-14     |  1      |  0
1234   | GUI       | 27-MAR-14     |  0      |  0
1234   | GUI       | 27-JUN-14     |  1      |  0
1234   | GUI       | 27-SEPT-14    |  0      |  1
1234   | GUI       | 27-SEPT-15    |  0      |  1
1234   | REMOTE    | 27-MAR-14     |  0      |  0
1234   | REMOTE    | 27-JUN-14     |  1      |  0
1234   | REMOTE    | 27-SEPT-14    |  0      |  1
2431   | cc        | 27-MAR-14     |  0      |  0
2431   | cc        | 27-JUN-14     |  1      |  0
```

I have a query like below

```
select a.reg_id, b.sess_start_dt,
 case when TRUNC(A.EVENT_DATE) - B.SESS_START_DT BETWEEN 0-30 THEN 'DAYS    0_30'
 WHEN TRUNC(A.EVENT_DATE) - B.SESS_START_DT BETWEEN 31-60 THEN 'DAYS 31-60' 
    from tab a inner join tab b on a.reg_id = b.reg_id and a.is_ren = 1  

union

select a.reg_id, b.sess_start_dt,
 case when TRUNC(A.EVENT_DATE) - B.SESS_START_DT BETWEEN 0-30 THEN 'DAYS    0_30'
 WHEN TRUNC(A.EVENT_DATE) - B.SESS_START_DT BETWEEN 31-60 THEN 'DAYS 31-60' 
    from tab a inner join tab b on a.reg_id = b.reg_id and a.is_con = 1
```

Tab B contains all the usage for each reg_id there will be 100's of records.. Sample of few are

```
  REGID | SESS_START_DT
  1234  | 27-Jan-14 
  1234  | 20-MAR-12
  1234  | 27-MAR-12
  1234  | 01-sept-14 
  1234  | 07-sept-14
  1234  | 29-JUL-14
  1234  | 03-AUG-14
  1234  | 27-MAR-13
  1234  | 27-MAR-12 
  1234  | 27-MAR-12 
  1234  | 27-MAR-12 
  1234  | 27-MAR-12 
  1234  | 27-MAR-12 
  1234  | 27-MAR-12 
  2431  | 20-JUN-14
```

The Above query needs to be corrected in a way like,

`1) If the REG_ID is having at least one is_ren = 1 then that subscription should be considered as renewal subscription and needs to get the 30 days and 60 days usage from table B from his is_ren = 1 event_date. (for REGID 1234 only is_ren query should execute)`

`2) If multiple IS_REN = 1 are existing for each REGID then the usage needs to be taken 30 days and 60 days from table B with the MIN(event_date). in this case the usage should be taken from  27-SEPT-14  instead of 27-SEPT-15`

`3) If there is no IS_REN = 1 and there is IS_CON = 1  then it's considered as conversion and usage should be taken before 60 days from the converted date (for REGID 2431, usage needs to get 60 days back from 27-JUN-14{this is my event_date in the query})`

The O/P should be like

```
REGID     |  EVENT_DATE     |   DAYS    0_30   |  DAYS 31-60  | CODE
1234      |  27-SEPT-14     |   2              |  2           | REN
2431      |  27-JUL-14      |   1              |  0           | CON
```

Comment: Can you please define terms like "get the 30 days and 60 days usage from table B" and "usage needs to get 60 days back from ..." - these are not database terms (at least not Oracle terms). Demonstrating sample output may help.

Comment: okay I am following most of this, though I would suggest your definition of usage is a bit unclear.  But how do you want your desired output?  Rows For Renewal and Rows for Conversion, Columns for them? You should add desired result based on your example

Comment: @mathguy - If you remember you have provided me a solutions for this few days back. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38318535/oracle-sql-how-to-get-counts-based-up-on-dates-into-multiple-columns-in-oracle/38318785#38318785 .. There we have used Sysdate and here we need to use event_date. I need to determine which event_date to use and that's all my question is about :)

Comment: @Matt -- Hi Matt, I can convert the rows to columns by using Pivot. If you can provide me at row level that should suffice.

Comment: Actually either are just as easy, but please update your question and add expected results because for some reasons I am not getting the concept of what you want to compare to determine days differenc.  EVENT_DATE to Andy SESS_START_DATE witihin -60 days?  And then what summarize those up by REGID?  I have a feeling it will be way more clear if you include expected results.

Comment: @ Matt - I have included the expected results. Kindly please let me know of any more information. Thanks for your help.

Comment: OK... if there are multiple rows with `is_ren = 1` you take the `min(event_date)` - min over what? I assume over the rows with `is_ren = 1` only, or is it over all the rows? Similarly in 3, if there is no row with `is_ren =1` and there are one or more rows with `is_con = 1`, then do you take the `min(event_date)` only over the rows with `is_con = 1`? And what should happen if for a `regid` all the `is_con` and `is_ren` are 0 (or not equal to 1, if there may be other values)? Can you have NULL in any of the columns and if so what should happen then?

Comment: @mathguy - 1) Yes min over `is_ren = 1` rows only. 2) Similarly for 3 also we need to take the `min(event_date)` over `is_con = 1`  rows only3) I am not bothered about the reg_id's that doesn't have either of is_ren = 1 or is_con = 1. (This req is only to get the usage for is_ren = 1 or is_con = 1 4) No Nulls are expected.

Comment: @matt - can you please post your solution too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If my assumptions in my Comment are correct, this may be what you need. Notice the `order by` clause in `row_number()` - first the rows with `is_ren = 1`, then the rows with `is_ren = 0` and `is_con = 1`, then all the other rows, and within each group order by `event_date` ascending. This way, the top row (`rn = 1`), which is the only one I use in the outer query, will have `is_ren = 1` with the earliest possible date, or if no `is_ren = 1` then the row with `is_con = 1` and the earliest date, or else just the earliest date. (In the last case, the `CODE` will be null: this means there were no `is_ren = 1` and no `is_con = 1` for that `regid`.

Not sure why you have `27-JUL-14` in the output for `regid = 2431`, that should be `27-JUN-14`. Also, there are no four-letter months in Oracle ("SEPT"). The output shows dates using my session parameters; if you need to format the dates, use `to_date(event_date, .....)` with the desired date format model. Also, since the data you provided is just dates (with no time-of-day component), I didn't truncate anything; you may need to, if your real data has time-of-day components.

```
with
     table_a ( regid, pkg_desc, event_date, is_con, is_ren ) as (
       select 1234, 'cc'    , to_date ('27-MAR-14', 'dd-MON-rr'), 0, 0 from dual union all
       select 1234, 'cc'    , to_date ('27-JUN-14', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1, 0 from dual union all
       select 1234, 'GUI'   , to_date ('27-MAR-14', 'dd-MON-rr'), 0, 0 from dual union all
       select 1234, 'GUI'   , to_date ('27-JUN-14', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1, 0 from dual union all
       select 1234, 'GUI'   , to_date ('27-SEP-14', 'dd-MON-rr'), 0, 1 from dual union all
       select 1234, 'GUI'   , to_date ('27-SEP-15', 'dd-MON-rr'), 0, 1 from dual union all
       select 1234, 'REMOTE', to_date ('27-MAR-14', 'dd-MON-rr'), 0, 0 from dual union all
       select 1234, 'REMOTE', to_date ('27-JUN-14', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1, 0 from dual union all
       select 1234, 'REMOTE', to_date ('27-SEP-14', 'dd-MON-rr'), 0, 1 from dual union all
       select 2431, 'cc'    , to_date ('27-MAR-14', 'dd-MON-rr'), 0, 0 from dual union all
       select 2431, 'cc'    , to_date ('27-JUN-14', 'dd-MON-rr'), 1, 0 from dual
     ),
     table_b ( regid, sess_start_dt ) as (
       select 1234, to_date ('27-JAN-14', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('20-MAR-12', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('27-MAR-12', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('01-SEP-14', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('07-SEP-14', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('29-JUL-14', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('03-AUG-14', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('27-MAR-13', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('27-MAR-12', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('27-MAR-12', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('27-MAR-12', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('27-MAR-12', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('27-MAR-12', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 1234, to_date ('27-MAR-12', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual union all
       select 2431, to_date ('20-JUN-14', 'dd-MON-rr') from dual
     ),
     prep ( regid, event_date, code, rn ) as (
       select regid, event_date,
              case when is_ren = 1 then 'REN' when is_con = 1 then 'CON' else null end,
              row_number() over (partition by regid 
                                 order by case when is_ren = 1 then 0
                                               when is_con = 1 then 1 else 2 end, 
                                 event_date)
       from   table_a
     )
select p.regid, p.event_date,
       count(case when b.sess_start_dt between p.event_date - 30 and p.event_date
                                                            then 1 end) as days_0_30,
       count(case when b.sess_start_dt between p.event_date - 60 and p.event_date - 31 
                                                            then 1 end) as days_31_60,
       p.code
from   prep p inner join table_b b on p.regid = b.regid
where  rn = 1
group by p.regid, p.event_date, p.code
;
```

**Output**:

```
     REGID EVENT_DATE           DAYS_0_30 DAYS_31_60 COD
---------- ------------------- ---------- ---------- ---
      1234 2014-09-27 00:00:00          2          2 REN
      2431 2014-06-27 00:00:00          1          0 CON
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the solution. That works. Is there any way we can divide this query into the 2 parts, one for Renewal and one for Conversion each and do union after that?

Comment: Yes, and it's actually easier to write - but less efficient. You would do twice the amount of work to get the two separate result sets, and then a little more to `union` them. Also, the `CON` part would be complicated because you would need to ignore the `regid`'s that have an `is_ren = 1`; this is extra work. What Oracle version do you have? In Oracle 12, there is `fetch first` which can help do away the subquery - outer query structure using `row_number()`.

Comment: I am using Oracle 11i. I have no problem using the above query but I have one small problem though. Actually the reason why I have asked is, in the real data I have event_date is coming from 2 different columns. for is_con, the event_date is coming from is_con_event_date column and for is_ren, the event_date is coming from is_ren_event_date column.

Comment: I am using Oracle 11i. I have no problem using the above query but I have one small problem though. Actually the reason why I have asked is, in the real data I have event_date is coming from 2 different columns. for is_con, the event_date is coming from is_con_event_date column and for is_ren, the event_date is coming from is_ren_event_date column. Is there a way at least I use is_con_event_date for is_con = 1 and is_ren_event_date for is_ren = 1

Comment: Yes, that is easy. In the `prep` subquery, instead of `event_date` (not in the list of column names, but in the actual `select` clause) use `case when is_ren = 1 then ren_event_date when is_con = 1 then con_event_date end` (note: if neither `when` condition succeeds, the date returned will be `null` which is OK if I understand correctly. Also, the order of the two is important!)

Comment: above query is working perfectly fine if i remove SUBSCRIPTION_ACTION_DATE in the row_number() clause. I will post the working query below. Can you let me know what mistake I am doing?

Comment: Ugh - you are right, I forgot `event_date` is used there as well. You will need to substitute the same `case` expression in that place as well: instead of `order by event_date` it should be `order by case when is_renewal = 1 then package_renewal_date ....` (etc.), just like in the other place.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121774/discussion-between-beckham-and-mathguy).